# Incorrect values returned from $this->$xxxx fields

Tags: wordpress, oop, this

I have a problem with getting shortcode values into variables, you advise please? 
This is the code:

```
class virtual_cheshire_ring
```

{

```
public $start_date              =   '';
public $end_date                =   '';
public $db_table_participants   =   '';
public $db_table_log            =   '';
public function __construct()
{
    add_shortcode('virtual_crr', array($this, 'virtual_crr') );
}

public function virtual_crr($atts)
{   
    //******************************
    //** Get shortcode parameters **
    //******************************
    global $post;
            $shortcode_defaults = [ 'start_date' => '2020-01-01',
                            'end_date'  =>  '2050-00-01',
                            'db_table_participants' =>  'db_table_participants',
                            'db_table_log'  =>  'db_table_log',
                          ];
    $attributes = array_merge($shortcode_defaults,$atts);

    $this->$start_date              = $attributes['start_date'];
    $this->$end_date                = $attributes['end_date'];
    $this->$db_table_participants   = $attributes['db_table_participants'];
    $this->$db_table_log            = $attributes['db_table_log'];

    var_dump($attributes);

    $html  = 'start_date = ' . $this->$start_date . ' / ' . $attributes['start_date'] . '<br>';
    $html .= 'end_date = ' . $this->$end_date . ' / ' . $attributes['end_date'] . '<br>';
    $html .= 'db_table_participants = ' . $this->$db_table_participants . ' / ' . $attributes['db_table_participants'] . "<br>";
    $html .= 'db_table_log = ' . $this->$db_table_log . ' / ' . $attributes['db_table_log'] . '<br>';
    return $html;
}
```

}

The shortcode on the webpage is:
[virtual_crr start_date="2020-06-02" end_date="2020-06-30"]

The var_dump($attributes) returns:

array (size=4)
  'start_date' => string '2020-06-02' (length=10)

'end_date' => string '2020-06-30' (length=10)

'db_table_participants' => string 'db_table_participants' (length=21)

'db_table_log' => string 'db_table_log' (length=12)

The output on the webpage is:

start_date = db_table_log / 2020-06-02

end_date = db_table_log / 2020-06-30

db_table_participants = db_table_log / db_table_participants

db_table_log = db_table_log / db_table_log

So clearly I'm not understanding something fundamental as the '$this->$xxxx values differ from the $attributes array values, can you advise please?

Many thanks in advance

Alan

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `$` from your param when you access them with `$this`.

So it would look more like:

```
<?php
public function virtual_crr($atts)
{   
  //******************************
  //** Get shortcode parameters **
  //******************************
  global $post;

  $shortcode_defaults = [
    'start_date' => '2020-01-01',
    'end_date'  =>  '2050-00-01',
    'db_table_participants' =>  'db_table_participants',
    'db_table_log'  =>  'db_table_log',
  ];
  $attributes = array_merge($shortcode_defaults,$atts);

  $this->start_date              = $attributes['start_date'];
  $this->end_date                = $attributes['end_date'];
  $this->db_table_participants   = $attributes['db_table_participants'];
  $this->db_table_log            = $attributes['db_table_log'];

  var_dump($attributes);

  $html  = 'start_date = ' . $this->start_date . ' / ' . $attributes['start_date'] . '<br>';
  $html .= 'end_date = ' . $this->end_date . ' / ' . $attributes['end_date'] . '<br>';
  $html .= 'db_table_participants = ' . $this->db_table_participants . ' / ' . $attributes['db_table_participants'] . "<br>";
  $html .= 'db_table_log = ' . $this->db_table_log . ' / ' . $attributes['db_table_log'] . '<br>';

  return $html;
}
?>
```